# k nearest neighbor in SAS: how to get the neighbor list for each row?

Tags: machine-learning, sas, bigdata, nearest-neighbor, knn

currently I'm using the proc discrim in SAS to run a kNN analysis for a data set, but the problem may require me to get the top k neighbor list for each rows in my table, so how can I get this list from SAS??

thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for the neighbor list for each data point, for example if i got data set:
name age zipcode alcohol 
John  26  08439   yes
Cathy 49  47789   no
smith 37  90897   no
Tom   34  88642   yes

then i need list:

name neighbor1 neighbor2
John  Tom       cathy
Cathy Tom       Smith
Smith Cathy     Tom
Tom   John      Cathy

I could not find this output from SAS, is there any whay that I can program to get this list? Thank you!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for the neighbor list for each data point, for example if i got data set:

Comment: A similar question was asked here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276866/how-to-use-nearest-neighbor-to-find-similar-population-based-on-list-of-features/279934#279934

Answer (score 1):

I am not a SAS user, but a quick web lookup seems to give a good answers for your problem:

As far as i know you do not have to implement it by yourself. DISCRIM is enough.

Code for iris data from http://www.sas-programming.com/2010/05/k-nearest-neighbor-in-sas.html

```
ods select none;
proc surveyselect data=iris  out=iris2  
                  samprate=0.5  method=srs  outall;
run;
ods select all;

%let k=5;
proc discrim data=iris2(where=(selected=1))   
             test=iris2(where=(selected=0))
             testout=iris2testout
             method=NPAR k=&k 
             listerr crosslisterr; 
      class Species; 
      var SepalLength SepalWidth PetalLength PetalWidth; 
      title2 'Using KNN on Iris Data'; 
run;
```

The long and detailed description is also avaliable here:
http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2012/SD-09.pdf

And from the sas community:

> Simply ask PROC DISCRIM to use nonparametric method by using option "METHOD=NPAR K=". Note that do not use "R=" option at the same time, which corresponds to radius-based of nearest-neighbor method. Also pay attention to how PROC DISCRIM treat categorical data automatically. Sometimes, you may want to change categorical data into metric coordinates in advance. Since PROC DISCRIM doesn't output the Tree it built internally, use "data= test= testout=" option to score new data set.